# Excel macro Select Case

Tags: vba, excel

```
SM1 = "5000"
SM = "SPOTMARKET"
SM = "*" & SM & "*"

Select Case Cells(H + 2, 24).Value
            Case SM,SM1
             C(j) = "SPOTMARKET"

        End Select
```

I'm trying to make something like that but the "SM" doesn't work as it suppose to. I want that C(J) = "SPOTMARKET" when Cells(H + 2, 24) has the word spotmarket in it. it could be WRER-SPOTMARKET or the opposite SPOTMARKET-WRER.

This lines are inside For j=0 to XXX and For H=0 to XXX. C is an array.

THANK YOU

Comment: What is `C`? And what does `H + 2` mean - column J?

Comment: you're using `"*"` as a wild card ?

Comment: What im trying to do there is that SM means anything that has inside the word SPOTMARKET. And yes as a wild card

Comment: Yes, that's what a wild card means (the `*`stands for anything).

You'll have to used `LIKE` operator for comparison. Check this thread. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409418/excel-vba-select-case-if-activecell-like-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `InStr` to test for whether "SPOTMARKET" is found.

```
If InStr(Cells(H + 2, 24), "SPOTMARKET") > 0 Then
    C(j) = "SPOTMARKET"
ElseIf InStr(Cells(H + 2, 24), "FORWARDMARKET") > 0 Then
    C(j) = "FORWARDMARKET" 
End If
```

`InStr` returns 0 if no match and an integer > 0 if found.

Comment: This works perfect but how do i add another word ? im trying to add one more word like Spotmarket tothe InStr but it gives me error all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Now it should work:

```
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim sm1
    Dim k

    k = "lalal SPOTMARKET ale"
    sm1 = "5000"

    Select Case True
        Case k Like "*SPOTMARKET*", sm1
            Debug.Print "Found"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Here is an article with good examples for like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Comment: How come? In my console the following: <start>?"LALALALA   SPOTMARKET LALALALA LALALA" like "*SPOTMARKET*" <end> returns true, thus it should. Note - The stars before and after the second spotmarket are removed from stackoverflow.

Comment: it asks for something liek = > > ...etc