# Select Case with multiple "Like" conditions

Tags: excel, vba, switch-statement, select-case

I am trying to reduce a large `If statement` by creating a smaller `Case statement`.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but here is what I have so far.

It is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409418/excel-vba-select-case-if-activecell-like-string), but doesn't address the multiple situations and one result of my issue.

```
With tempWB.Worksheets(1)
    rwCnt = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row
    .Rows(rwCnt).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    rwCnt = rwCnt - 1

    For y = rwCnt to 2 step -1
        'Delete Non-Individuals
        Select Case .Cells(y, 1).Value2
            Case (.Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like ("* TRUST *" Or "* AND *" Or "* & *" Or "* OF *" Or _
            "* LLC*" Or "* REV TR *" Or "* LV TR *" Or "* BY *" Or "*'S *" Or "C/O*"))
                .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End Select
    Next y

'        If .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* TRUST *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* AND *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* & *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* OF *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* LLC*" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* REV TR *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* LV TR *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* BY *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "*'S *" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        ElseIf .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "C/O*" Then
'            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
'        End If


End With
```

Below the `Case statement` is the `If statement` that works great, it just looks clunky and I think a `Case statement` would simplify things a bit.  I'm just not 100% sure how to implement it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See in that linked post that you need to use `Select Case True`. The result of a `Like` comparison is a `Boolean`. That said, you'd need to repeat the `.Cells(y, 1).Value2`, you can't string together the right side of `Like` like you're trying to.

Comment: @BigBen - So because the conditions use a `wildcard` and `like` I can't make it a lot shorter?

Comment: It's because the `Like` comparison returns a `Boolean`. The wildcard has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @BigBen - But the wildcard won't  work without a `Like`. So, the `case statement` would need to be just as long as the `If statement`

Comment: It would be slightly shorter because you'd only have one instance of `.Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't string together the right side of that `Like` comparison like you're attempting to.

Also, as noted in the linked post, you need to use `Select Case True`, because the result of a `Like` comparison is a `Boolean`.

The `Select Case` could then look something like this:

```
Select Case True
    Case .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* TRUST *", _
         .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* AND *", _
         .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* & *", _ 
         '... and so on

        .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Case True as was pointed out in the comments.

```
   Select Case True
        Case .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* TRUST *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* AND *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* & *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* OF *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* LLC*" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* REV TR *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* LV TR *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "* BY *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "*'S *" _
        Or .Cells(y, 1).Value2 Like "C/O*"
            .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    End Select
```

An alternative is to write a function to iterate over the conditions:

```
Function Likes(Value As Variant, ParamArray Conditions() As Variant)
    Dim Condition
    For Each Condition In Conditions
        If Value Like Condition Then
            Likes = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

### Usage

> ```
> If Likes(.Cells(y, 1).Value2, "* TRUST *", "* AND *", "* & *", "* OF *", "* LLC*", "* REV TR *", "* LV TR *", "* BY *", "*'S *", "C/O*") Then
>     .Rows(y).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
> End If
> ```